# Someone shared my picture

Tags: facebook

I posted a picture on Facebook, and one of my Facebook friends shared it with a message I don't want.

Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Did he/she share your post? Then I believe it should disappear if you remove your post.

If the person made a copy of the image it's trickier, or even impossible. You could try reporting it (open the image, press options then report image), but I'm not sure Facebook removes it if it isn't disturbing for the general public.

You really have to be careful with what images (and everything else) you share with people. If you upload something on the internet you have to be prepared for it to spread.